# Filter the parent model instances based on an attribute of the associated model in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to get the `User`s of a particular `city` in the `userprofile` model. My code is as below:

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='Bengaluru', blank=False, null=False)
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    users = User.objects.filter(is_staff=False).prefetch_related(
                                                        Prefetch('userprofile',
                                                                  queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(city='Mumbai')
                                                        )
                                                    )
    context = { 'users': users }
    return render(request, 'users/home.html', context)
```

But in the above code, `users` object contains all the `users` but the `userprofile`s only where the `city` is `Mumbai`. What I want is do get only the `user`s whose `userprofile` `city` is `Mumbai`. Not all the `user`s. How can I do that? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem:

```
users = User.objects.filter(
    is_staff=False,
    userprofile__city='Mumbai'
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('userprofile',
              queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(city='Mumbai')
)
                                                    )
```

If there is any other better way then please post your answer.